# Cannot run an image in Docker

Tags: docker

I created an image called "**helloworld**" based on some project I have.

If I run :

> docker images

I can see it there on top of the list.

[image]

Now if I want to run it, docker complains it does not exist.

Running this :

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 helloworld
```

returns this :

> docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for helloworld,
> repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied:
> requested access to the resource is denied. See 'docker run --help'.

Why is docker complaining that my image does not exist?

Answer (score 2):

It complains, because this:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 helloworld
```

is a shortened version of this:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 docker.io/library/helloworld:latest
```

and, based on the screenshot, your image is called

```
docker.io/library/helloworld:1.0
```

so the proper command (skipping default prefix) is:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 helloworld:1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Your image build command:

```
docker build --rm -f "Dockerfile" -t helloworld:1.0 "."
```

Meaning your image name is `helloworld:1.0`

If you had run `docker build --rm -f "Dockerfile" -t helloworld "."`

Then your image name is `helloworld` or `helloworld:latest` and your first try would have worked.

To solve your issue run this instead:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 helloworld:1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Other answers are correct but don't explain clearly why they are correct.

The `docker run` command expects an image name and, optionally, a tag (i.e., `docker run IMAGE[:TAG]`). If a tag is not provided, the default is `latest`.

Running `docker run helloworld` is equivalent to `docker run helloworld:latest`, but this image does not exist in the OP's system according to `docker images`.

The solution is to specify the image tag: `helloworld:1.0`.